# Given n files with their lengths, divide total bytes equally among d threads equally such that any two threads differ by atmost 1 byte

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, file-handling

You are given a list of file names and their lengths in bytes.

Example:

File1: 200 File2: 500 File3: 800

You are given a number N. We want to launch N threads to read all the files parallelly such that each thread approximately reads an equal amount of bytes 
You should return N lists. Each list describes the work of one thread: Example, when N=2, there are two threads. In the above example, there is a total of 1500 bytes (200 + 500 + 800). A fairway to divide is for each thread to read 750 bytes. So you will return:

Two lists

List 1: File1: 0 - 199 File2: 0 - 499 File3: 0-49 ---------------- Total 750 bytes

List 2: File3: 50-799 -------------------- Total 750 bytes

Implement the following method

```
List<List<FileRange>> getSplits(List<File> files, int N) 
Class File { 
String filename; long length } 
Class FileRange { 
String filename Long startOffset Long endOffset } 
I tried with this one but it's not working any help would be highly appreciated.
List<List<FileRange>> getSplits(List<File> files, int n) {
        List<List<FileRange>> al=new ArrayList<>();
        long s=files.size();
        long sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
            long l=files.get(i).length;
            sum+=(long)l;
        }
        long div=(long)sum/n; // no of bytes per thread
        long mod=(long)sum%n;
        long[] lo=new long[(long)n];
        for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
        lo[i]=div;
        if(mod!=0){
            long i=0;
            while(mod>0){
                lo[i]+=1;
                mod--;
                i++;
            }
        }
        long inOffset=0;
        for(long j=0;j<n;j++){
            long val=lo[i];
        for(long i=0;i<(long)files.size();i++){
            String ss=files.get(i).filename;
            long ll=files.get(i).length;
                if(ll<val){
                    inOffset=0;
                    val-=ll;
                }
                else{
                    inOffset=ll-val;
                    ll=val;
                }
                al.add(new ArrayList<>(new File(ss,inOffset,ll-1)));
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm getting problem in startOffset and endOffset with it's corresponding file. I tried it but I was not able to extract from List and add in the form of required return type List>.

Comment: I don't know what will be the next startoffset and endOffset.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the problem is to simultaneously walk through two lists:

- the input list, which is a list of files
- the output list, which is a list of threads (where each thread has a list of ranges)

I find that the easiest approach to such problems is an infinite loop that looks something like this:

```
while (1)
{
    move some information from the input to the output
    decide whether to advance to the next input item
    decide whether to advance to the next output item
    if we've reached (the end of the input _OR_ the end of the output)
        break
    if we advanced to the next input item
        prepare the next input item for processing
    if we advanced to the next output item
        prepare the next output item for processing
}
```

To keep track of the input, we need the following information

- `fileIndex` the index into the list of files
- `fileOffset` the offset of the first unassigned byte in the file, initially 0
- `fileRemain` the number of bytes in the file that are unassigned, initially the file size

To keep track of the output, we need

- `threadIndex` the index of the thread we're currently working on (which is the first index into the `List<List<FileRange>>` that the algorithm produces)
- `threadNeeds` the number of bytes that the thread still needs, initially `base` or `base+1`

Side note: I'm using `base` as the minimum number bytes assigned to each thread (`sum/n`), and `extra` as the number of threads that get an extra byte (`sum%n`).

So now we get to the heart of the algorithm: what information to move from input to output:

- if `fileRemain` is less than `threadNeeds` then the rest of the file (which may be the entire file) gets assigned to the current thread, and we move to the next file
- if `fileRemain` is greater than `threadNeeds` then a portion of the file is assigned to the current thread, and we move to the next thread
- if `fileRemain` is equal to `threadNeeds` then the rest of the file is assigned to the thread, and we move to the next file, and the next thread

Those three cases are easily handled by comparing `fileRemain` and `threadNeeds`, and choosing a `byteCount` that is the minimum of the two.

With all that in mind, here's some pseudo-code to help get you started:

```
base  = sum/n;
extra = sum%n;

// initialize the input control variables
fileIndex  = 0
fileOffset = 0
fileRemain = length of file 0

// initialize the output control variables
threadIndex = 0
threadNeeds = base
if (threadIndex < extra)
    threadNeeds++

while (1)
{
    // decide how many bytes can be assigned, and generate some output
    byteCount = min(fileRemain, threadNeeds)
    add (file.name, fileOffset, fileOffset+byteCount-1) to the list of ranges

    // decide whether to advance to the next input and output items
    threadNeeds -= byteCount
    fileRemain  -= byteCount
    if (threadNeeds == 0)
        threadIndex++
    if (fileRemain == 0)
        fileIndex++

    // are we done yet?
    if (threadIndex == n || fileIndex == files.size())
        break

    // if we've moved to the next input item, reinitialize the input control variables
    if (fileRemain == 0)
    {
        fileOffset = 0
        fileRemain = length of file
    }

    // if we've moved to the next output item, reinitialize the output control variables
    if (threadNeeds == 0)
    {
        threadNeeds = base
        if (threadIndex < extra)
            threadNeeds++
    }
}
```

Debugging tip: Reaching the end of the input, and the end of the output, should happen simultaneously. In other words, you should run out of files at exactly the same time as you run out of threads. So during development, I would check both conditions, and verify that they do, in fact, change at the same time.

Comment: great pseudo-code and explanation; although I would have preferred to either place the `break` condition in the `while` loop itself, or use a boolean `finished` variable to exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code solution for your problem (in Java) :

The custom class 'File' and 'FileRange' are as follows :

```
public class File{

    String filename;
    long length;

    public File(String filename, long length) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public long getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(long length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
}
```

```
public class FileRange {

    String filename;
    Long startOffset;
    Long endOffset;

    public FileRange(String filename, Long startOffset, Long endOffset) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.startOffset = startOffset;
        this.endOffset = endOffset;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public Long getStartOffset() {
        return startOffset;
    }

    public void setStartOffset(Long startOffset) {
        this.startOffset = startOffset;
    }

    public Long getEndOffset() {
        return endOffset;
    }

    public void setEndOffset(Long endOffset) {
        this.endOffset = endOffset;
    }
}
```

The main class will be as follows :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MainClass {

    private static List<List<FileRange>> getSplits(List<File> files, int N) {

        List<List<FileRange>> results = new ArrayList<>();

        long sum = files.stream().mapToLong(File::getLength).sum();     // Total bytes in all the files

        long div = sum/N;

        long mod = sum%N;

        // Storing how many bytes each thread gets to process
        long thread_bytes[] = new long[N];

        // At least 'div' number of bytes will be processed by each thread
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            thread_bytes[i] = div;

        // Left over bytes to be processed by each thread
        for(int i=0;i<mod;i++)
            thread_bytes[i] += 1;

        int count = 0;

        int len = files.size();

        long processed_bytes[] = new long[len];

        long temp = 0L;

        int file_to_be_processed = 0;

        while(count < N && sum > 0) {

            temp = thread_bytes[count];

            sum -= temp;

            List<FileRange> internal = new ArrayList<>();

            while (temp > 0) {

                // Start from the file to be processed - Will be 0 in the first iteration
                // Will be updated in the subsequent iterations
                for(int j=file_to_be_processed;j<len && temp>0;j++){

                    File f = files.get(j);

                    if(f.getLength() - processed_bytes[j] <= temp){

                        internal.add(new FileRange(f.getFilename(), processed_bytes[j], f.getLength()- 1));

                        processed_bytes[j] = f.getLength() - processed_bytes[j];

                        temp -= processed_bytes[j];

                        file_to_be_processed++;

                    }

                    else{

                        internal.add(new FileRange(f.getFilename(), processed_bytes[j], processed_bytes[j] + temp - 1));

                        // In this case, we won't update the number for file to be processed
                        processed_bytes[j] += temp;

                        temp -= processed_bytes[j];

                    }

                }

                results.add(internal);

                count++;

            }

        }
        return results;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = scn.nextInt();

        // Inserting demo records in list

        File f1 = new File("File 1",200);
        File f2 = new File("File 2",500);
        File f3 = new File("File 3",800);

        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

        files.add(f1);
        files.add(f2);
        files.add(f3);

        List<List<FileRange>> results = getSplits(files, N);

        final AtomicInteger result_count = new AtomicInteger();

        // Displaying the results

        results.forEach(result -> {

            System.out.println("List "+result_count.incrementAndGet() + " : ");

            result.forEach(res -> {

                System.out.print(res.getFilename() + " : ");
                System.out.print(res.getStartOffset() + " - ");
                System.out.print(res.getEndOffset() + "\n");

            });

            System.out.println("---------------");

        });

    }

}
```

If some part is still unclear, consider a case and dry run the program. 
Say **999** bytes have to be processed by **100** threads
So the 100 threads get 9 bytes each and out of the remaining 99 bytes, each thread except the 100th gets 1 byte. By doing this, we'll make sure no 2 threads differ by at most 1 byte. Proceed with this idea and follow up with the code.